# How to find table names ending with digits from hive database?

Tags: database, hive, hiveql

How can i find table names which end with digits in hive ?

I tried some combinations like `show tables like "%[0-9]%";` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `hive` from shell and filter results using `grep`, like this:

```
 hive -e "use your_schema; show tables;" | grep '[0-9]$'
```